# Is it possible to return into 2 variable in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

```
//Create Borang Pendaftaran
public function CreateForm()
{
    $names = DB::table('pendaftaran')
    ->where('isActive',1)
    ->orderBy('id','desc')
    ->get();

    $names2 = DB::table('pendaftaran')
    ->where('isActive',0)
    ->orderBy('id','desc')
    ->get();

    return view('contact',['names' =>$names]); 
}
```

The changes I made is

return view('contact',['names' =>$names,$names2]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must put $names and $names2 into a array.
example

```
$arr_names = [$names, $names2];
return view('contact',['names' =>$arr_names]);
```

or

```
return view('contact',['names'=> $names,'names2'=>$names2]);
```

Comment: I got problem when i run it. Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel 8\ContactForm\resources\views\contact.blade.php)

Comment: the 2nd one is working perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

use this one:

```
 $contact= [
    'name'  => $names,
    'names2'   => $names2,
   
 ];
 return view('contact',comapact('contact');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use two variables in your view, in your blade you just use `activeNames` and `inactiveNames` instead

```
return view('contact',[
  'activeNames' => $names,
  'inactiveNames' => $names2,
]);

// Then in blade

@foreach($activeNames as $activeName) 
  {{ $activeName }}
@endforeach

@foreach($inactiveNames as $inactiveName)
  {{ $activeName }}
@endforeach
```

If you want to use single $names in view, then you shouldn't have used the `->where` in your query, just grab all of them.

```
$names = DB::table('pendaftaran')
    ->orderBy('id','desc')
    ->get();

return view('contact',['names' =>$names]);
```

Comment: Thank you. but I got problem which is undefined variable